# Deep Storage in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, druid

While going through different columnar databases in Hadoop ecosystem, I came across the term "Deep Storage". I am not able to understand what deep storage means. Does deep storage mean Data Lake ? Is it different from data stored in  HDFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Druid setup, the Deep Storage is the place where the data (segments) can reliably be retrieved from, this can be HDFS, S3, Google Cloud, etc (there are connectors plugin available).

The Druid Historical node will retrieve the data from this deep storage during initial bootstrap and during rebalance.

Similarly, the MiddleManagers nodes, Realtime nodes, indexing tasks will write to Deep Storage and make the data available to the cluster.

In summary there is no exchange of data segment between nodes, Druid uses Deep Storage as the source of truth.